# SUM exactly using K elements solution

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, recurrence

Problem: On a given array with N numbers, find subset of size M (exactly M elements) that equal to SUM.

I am looking for a Dynamic Programming(DP) solution for this problem. Basically looking to understand the matrix filled approach. I wrote below program but didn't add memoization as i am still wondering how to do that.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define SIZE(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
    int binary[100];
    int a[] = {1, 2, 5, 5, 100};

    void show(int* p, int size) {
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
                    if (p[j])
                            printf("%d\n", a[j]);
    }

    void subset_sum(int target, int i, int sum, int *a, int size, int K) {
            if (sum == target && !K) {
                    show(binary, size);
            } else if (sum < target && i < size) {
                    binary[i] = 1;
                    foo(target, i + 1, sum + a[i], a, size, K-1);
                    binary[i] = 0;
                    foo(target, i + 1, sum, a, size, K);
            }
    }

    int main() {
            int target = 10;
            int K = 2;
            subset_sum(target, 0, 0, a, SIZE(a), K);
    }
```

Is the below recurrence solution makes sense?

Let DP[SUM][j][k] sum up to SUM with exactly K elements picked from 0 to j elements.

```
 DP[i][j][k] = DP[i][j-1][k] || DP[i-a[j]][j-1][k-1] { input array a[0....j] }
```

Base cases are:

```
DP[0][0][0] = DP[0][j][0] = DP[0][0][k] = 1
DP[i][0][0] = DP[i][j][0] = 0
```

It means we can either consider this element ( DP[i-a[j]][j-1][k-1] ) or we don't consider the current element (DP[i][j-1][k]). If we consider current element, k is reduced by 1 which reduces the elements that needs to be considered and same goes when current element is not considered i.e. K is not reduced by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks right to me.

Right now, you're basically backtracking over all possibilities and printing each solution. If you only want one solution, you could add a flag that you set when one solution was found and check before continuing with recursive calls.

For memoization, you should first get rid of the `binary` array, after which you can do something like this:

```
int memo[NUM_ELEMENTS][MAX_SUM][MAX_K]; 
bool subset_sum(int target, int i, int sum, int *a, int size, int K) {
            if (sum == target && !K) {
                    memo[i][sum][K] = true;
                    return memo[i][sum][K];
            } else if (sum < target && i < size) {
                    if (memo[i][sum][K] != -1)
                        return memo[i][sum][K];


                    memo[i][sum][K] = foo(target, i + 1, sum + a[i], a, size, K-1) || 
                                      foo(target, i + 1, sum, a, size, K);

                    return memo[i][sum][K]
            }

            return false;
    }
```

Then, look at `memo[_all indexes_][target][K]`. If this is true, there exists at least one solution. You can store addition information to get you that next solution, or you can iterate with an `i` from `found_index - 1` to `0` and check for which `i` you have `memo[i][sum - a[i]][K - 1] == true`. Then recurse on that, and so on. This will allow you to reconstruct the solution using just the `memo` array.

Comment: Base cases:memo[a[i]][0][0] = 1 for everything else 0 right for base case?
http://paste.ofcode.org/sQuVRSvUQpTaDd3VZYpdWZ is this code right for printing the elements? I will mark your answer right once you let me know your opinion.

Comment: @nomanpouigt haven't tested it, but the code looks right. Bases cases should be the same as for the original recursion.

Comment: @nomanpouigt I had a slight error in the code that caused it to memoize only true values. I fixed it now.

Comment: @IVlad: possible to add bases cases ?

Comment: @newbie_old Actually, I think there is no need to explicitly set any base cases, due to how the recursion works. The "base case" is the first `if` of the function. I have updated the answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, if only the feasibility of the input has to be checked, the problem can be solved with a two-dimensional state space

```
bool[][] IsFeasible = new bool[n][k]
```

where `IsFeasible[i][j]` is `true` if and only if there is a subset of the elements `1` to `i` which sum up to exactly `j` for every

```
1 <= i <= n
1 <= j <= k
```

and for this state space, the recurrence relation

```
IsFeasible[i][j] = IsFeasible[i-1][k-a[i]] || IsFeasible[i-1][k]
```

can be used, where the left-hand side of the or-operator `||` corresponds to selecting the `i`-th item and the right-hand side corresponds to to *not* selecting the `i`-th item. The actual choice of items could be obtained by backtracking or auxiliary information saved during evaluation.

Comment: no it is not about only feasibility. Your solution is same as subset sum but there is a added constraint about having only K elements which sums up to specific number.

Comment: Indeed, I misread the question; I will update my answer soon.